# The word "oblige" in this context

Tags: formal-language, indian-english

In formal applications it is quite obvious:

> Kindly grant me three days of leave and **oblige.**

Can I write it simply as:

> Kindly **oblige** me with three days of leave.

(As we have the construction--

**oblige somebody with something**

eg. Could you oblige me with a paper and a pen.)

Anyway, can I use **three days' leave** instead of **three days of leave?**

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence "... and oblige" is not correct. *Oblige* is being used intransitively, but not in any kind of typical fashion. (In fact, the syntax makes it more like a noun, but that doesn't exist.)

The second version "Kindly oblige me with three days of leave." is correct.

The second version is a bit too formal for me, and for a workplace context. It looks "Wedding invitation polite", and not the sort of thing that is written for a fairly everyday request to HR in a business.

"Three days' leave" is correct. I suspect that few people would actually use the apostrophe there, and say "Three days leave".

A simpler, plainer, less "Wedding-Invitation" would be,

> I would like three days' leave.